# Relation between thermal conductivity factor(k) and temperature coefficient of resistance(α)

Tags: pcb, temperature, heat, thermal

I'm trying to understand the thermal parameters affecting circuit design. I came across two different parameters.

- thermal conductivity factor(k) which is related to thermal impedance. The link to the article i came across is here

http://focus.ti.com/download/trng/docs/seminar/Topic%2010%20-%20Thermal%20Design%20Consideration%20for%20Surface%20Mount%20Layouts%20.pdf?DCMP=mdrvblog&HQS=gma-indu-motr-mdrvblog-150422-thermal-mc-en

- temperature coefficient of resistance which is generally specified in datasheets of electronic components.

I'm trying to make sense out of these two quantities. Are they related in some way?
Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They represent two different things:

- The **temperature coefficient of resistance** (or α) symbolizes the resistance change factor per degree of temperature change. Just as all materials have a certain specific resistance (at 20°C), they also change resistance according to temperature by certain amounts. (Source: [this page](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-12/temperature-coefficient-resistance/), where you can find a detailed explanation with examples.)
- The **thermal conductivity factor** only shows how easily the material conducts heat. As an example, metals get hot much faster than, for example, air or plastic. It is all written in details in the article you posted. ([here](http://focus.ti.com/download/trng/docs/seminar/Topic%2010%20-%20Thermal%20Design%20Consideration%20for%20Surface%20Mount%20Layouts%20.pdf?DCMP=mdrvblog&HQS=gma-indu-motr-mdrvblog-150422-thermal-mc-en))

Those two factors are not correlated to each other, as each one depends on the material and represent a different property.

Answer (score 0):

In a solar cell the light energy converts into thermal and chemical potential; eventually it transfers into electrical energy and a large portion retains as thermal loss.

At present, the solar cell temperature coefficient reduction approaches chemical passivation is ultimately reducing its heat related loss, thus efficiency is increasing.

The concept of passivation related  field effect the drift predominated over diffusion, thus thermal process diffusion must controlled by electro-chemical passivation. So, I think temperature co-efficient  may have relation to electrical and thermal conductivity variation process.